# How do I get the class attribute value using jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the class of the selected option and use that in a compare statement to find which class it is.

I get an undefined value. The option tag has a class set to it.

Why am I not getting a value back?

Html:

```
<select name="datagrid_filter" onchange="startFilter();">
    <option>All</option>
    <option disabled="true">Assignment:</option>
    <option disabled="true">Client:</option>
    <option disabled="true">Type:</option>
    <option class="type" value="Activity"> &nbsp Activity</option>
    <option class="type" value="Alert"> &nbsp Alert</option>
    <option class="type" value="Lead"> &nbsp Lead</option>
    <option class="type" value="Notification"> &nbsp Notification</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
var cs1 = $("option:selected", this).attr("class");
if(cs1 == 'Type'){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: change 'Type' to 'type' in js

Comment: i made the change, but the problem is that cs1 is undefined

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should change:

`onchange="startFilter();"` to `onchange="startFilter(this);"`

and in **startFilter** function:

```
function startFilter(ele){
    var className = $("option:selected", ele).attr("class");
    if(className == 'type'){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Take note that, the `this` inside **startFilter** function refers to the `window` object, not the element you bind it to.

Comment: Worked great, like in the above statement, I was referring to wrong object with my this. Needed to make sure right object was referenced. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `hasClass` jQuery API? It's very good in this case:

```
if($("option:selected", this).hasClass('type')){
    //do something
}
```

And make sure `this` referes to a proper object (as @undefined mentioned)
Or use:

```
if($("option:selected", "select[name=datagrid_filter]").hasClass('type')){
        //do something
    }
```

Or:

```
if($("select[name=datagrid_filter] option:selected").hasClass('type')){
            //do something
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to have inline JavaScript

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DQMct/)**

JavaScript

```
   $(function()
    {
        var handleChange    =   function()
                                {
                                    var $this     = $(this);
                                    var $selected = $this.children(":selected");
                                    var isType    = $selected.hasClass('type');
                                    if(isType)
                                    {
                                        alert('Do Something');                        
                                    }
                                };
        var $datagridFilter =  $('[name=datagrid_filter]')

        $datagridFilter.change(handleChange);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <select onchange="getval(this);" class="sele">
>    <option>All</option>
>     <option disabled="true">Assignment:</option>
>     <option disabled="true">Client:</option>
>     <option disabled="true">Type:</option>
>     <option class="type" value="Activity"> &nbsp Activity</option>
>     <option class="type" value="Alert"> &nbsp Alert</option>
>     <option class="type" value="Lead"> &nbsp Lead</option>
>     <option class="type" value="Notification"> &nbsp Notification</option>
> </select>
> <script>
>  function getval(sel)
> {
>
>     if($('.sele :selected').attr('class'))
>     {
>       console.log($('.sele :selected').attr("class","typ123"));
>           // Your code write here
>     }
>
> }
> </script>
> ```